# How to make DIV absolute+fixed?

Tags: html, scroll, fixed, absolute, scrollable

I want to make absolute DIV that can be scrolled down until it reaches top of the page, then it should became as fixed and stay on top until page is scrolled up again.

Comment: It's called a sticky nav. See: http://www.backslash.gr/demos/jquery-sticky-navigation/

Comment: You will need to code it so that the css changes when the top of the div hits the top of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code before closing head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var top = $('.div').offset().top;
function scroll(){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
if (scroll > top) { 
$('.div').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0 });
} else {
$('.div').css({ 'position': 'absolute','top': top }); 
} 
};
$(window).scroll(function() {
scroll();
});
});

</script>
<style>

body {height: 1000px;}
.header {height: 200px;}
.div {position: absolute;}

</style>
```

And use this code in body:

```
<div class="header">Header or logo company</div>
<div class="div"> text or menu or other </div>
```